Scroll multiple views with one ScrollView
I have two NSTextView in an HStack. The contents of each text view can exceed its horizontal space. I would like to control both text views with a single horizontal scroll bar.
Here is a clip of DiffMerge doing what I would like to do.
https://imgur.com/a/dJ9xduw
I have been using SwiftUI and have the current setup. In this configuration the horizontal scroll bar will scroll across the side-by-side views as one giant view. This result makes sense to me I'm just not sure how to get to the result I want.
import SwiftUI

struct DumbedDownRepresentable : NSViewRepresentable {
    typealias NSViewType = NSTextView
    
    func makeNSView(context: Context) -> NSTextView {
        let textView = TextView()
        for i in 1...50 {
            textView.string += String(repeating: "\(i) ", count: i)
            textView.string += "\n"
        }

        textView.textContainer?.widthTracksTextView = false
        textView.textContainer?.containerSize = CGSize(width: CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude, height: CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude)
        textView.isVerticallyResizable = true
        textView.isHorizontallyResizable = false
        textView.maxSize = CGSize(width: CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude, height: CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude)
        return textView
    }
    
    func updateNSView(_ nsView: NSTextView, context: Context) {
        
    }
    
    func sizeThatFits(_ proposal: ProposedViewSize, nsView: UXCodeTextView, context: Context) -> CGSize? {
        var size = nsView.intrinsicContentSize
        if let proposedWidth = proposal.width {
            size.width = max(proposedWidth, size.width)
        }
        return size
    }
    
    class TextView: NSTextView {
        override var intrinsicContentSize: NSSize {
            if let tc = self.textContainer, let lm = self.layoutManager {
                lm.ensureLayout(for: tc)
                return lm.usedRect(for: tc).size
            }
            return .zero
        }
    }
}

import SwiftUI

struct TestApp: App {
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ScrollView([.horizontal]) {
                HStack {
                    DumbedDownRepresentable()
                    DumbedDownRepresentable()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


Are you looking for a SwiftUI or NSScrollView solution?

@Willeke I am really up for any solution that will handle the use case. I am not tied to SwiftUI, just wound up there. I wound up tagging this as NSScrollView due to not being sure what the best tag is for this pertaining to scroll view tags.

Simple AppKit solution: each NSTextView has its own NSScrollView as usual. The horizontal scroll bar is a third NSScrollView. The width of the document view of the scroll bar NSScrollView is twice the width of the document view of the text views. The NSScrollViews are synchronized as documented in Synchronizing Scroll Views.
Set up:
leftScrollView.contentView.postsBoundsChangedNotifications = true
rightScrollView.contentView.postsBoundsChangedNotifications = true
scrolBarScrollView.contentView.postsBoundsChangedNotifications = true

NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: NSView.boundsDidChangeNotification,
    object: nil, queue: nil) { notification in
    if let contentView = notification.object as? NSClipView {
        self.boundsDidChange(contentView)
    }
}

When one of the NSScrollViews is scrolled (scroll bar, mouse wheel, selecting text, arrow keys):
func boundsDidChange(_ contentView: NSClipView) {
    // set width of the scroll bar scroll view, this should be done when the width of the text changes
    let width = max(leftScrollView.documentView?.frame.width ?? 0.0,
        rightScrollView.documentView?.frame.width ?? 0.0)
    scrolBarScrollView.documentView?.frame.size.width = width * 2
    
    // left or right view scrolled, synchronize scroll bar
    if contentView === leftScrollView.contentView || contentView === rightScrollView.contentView {
        let changedBoundsOrigin = contentView.documentVisibleRect.origin
        let curOffset = scrolBarScrollView.contentView.bounds.origin
        var newOffset = curOffset
        newOffset.x = changedBoundsOrigin.x * 2
        if curOffset != newOffset {
            scrolBarScrollView.contentView.scroll(to: newOffset)
            scrolBarScrollView.reflectScrolledClipView(scrolBarScrollView.contentView)
        }
    }
    // scroll bar scrolled, synchronize left and right view
    else if contentView === scrolBarScrollView.contentView {
        let changedBoundsOrigin = contentView.documentVisibleRect.origin
        for scrollView in [leftScrollView!, rightScrollView!] {
            let curOffset = scrollView.contentView.bounds.origin
            var newOffset = curOffset
            newOffset.x = changedBoundsOrigin.x / 2
            if curOffset != newOffset {
                scrollView.contentView.scroll(to: newOffset)
                scrollView.reflectScrolledClipView(scrollView.contentView)
            }
        }
    }
}


The best path forward I can identify is to make my own ScrollView. This implementation isn't complete but enough to provide an answere here.
struct TestApp: App {
    @State var hProgress: CGFloat = 0.0
    @State var vProgress: CGFloat = 0.0
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            GeometryReader() { geometry in
                Container {
                    HStack(alignment: .top, spacing: 0) {
                        DumbedDownRepresentable(hProgress: $hProgress, vProgress: $vProgress)
                            .frame(minWidth: (geometry.size.width - 20)/2) // 18 is magic number for vertical scroller
                        DumbedDownRepresentable(hProgress: $hProgress, vProgress: $vProgress)
                            .frame(minWidth: (geometry.size.width - 20)/2) // 18 is magic number for vertical scroller
                    }
                }
                .onPreferenceChange(HProgressKey.self) { value in
                    self.hProgress = value
                }
                .onPreferenceChange(VProgressKey.self) { value in
                    self.vProgress = value
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


struct Container<Content: View>: View {
    @ViewBuilder var content: Content
    var indicatorWidth: CGFloat = 20
    
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader() { geometry in
            VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 0) {
                HStack(alignment: .top, spacing: 0) {
                    content
                        .frame(height: geometry.size.height - indicatorWidth)
                    VerticalScrollBar()
                        .frame(height: geometry.size.height - indicatorWidth)
                }
                HorizontalScrollBar()
            }
        }
    }
}

struct VerticalScrollBar: View {
    @State var vOffset: CGFloat
    @State var barH: CGFloat = 0
    var barW: CGFloat = 20
    var indicatorH: CGFloat = 100
    var inset: CGFloat = 10
    
    init() {
        vOffset = inset
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Rectangle()
                .fill(.blue)
                .frame(maxWidth: barW, maxHeight: .infinity)
            RoundedRectangle(cornerSize: CGSize(width: 10, height: 10))
                .fill(.gray)
                .frame(width: barW/2, height: indicatorH)
                .gesture(DragGesture()
                    .onChanged() { value in
                        setVOffset(vOffset + value.translation.height)
                    }
                )
                .position(x: barW/2, y: indicatorH/2)
                .offset(y: vOffset)
                .preference(key:VProgressKey.self, value: progress())
                .onGeometryChange(for: CGSize.self) { proxy in
                    proxy.size
                } action: { newSize in
                    let progress = progress()
                    barH = newSize.height
                    setVOffset(progress * (barH-indicatorH-inset-inset))
                }
        }
    }
    
    func setVOffset(_ value: CGFloat) {
        vOffset = max(inset, value)
        vOffset = min(vOffset, barH-indicatorH-inset)
    }
    
    func progress() -> CGFloat {
        // TODO: divide by zero
        return (vOffset-inset) / (barH-indicatorH-inset-inset)
    }
}

struct HorizontalScrollBar: View {
    @State var hOffset: CGFloat
    @State var barW: CGFloat = 0
    var indicatorW: CGFloat = 100
    var barH: CGFloat = 20
    var inset: CGFloat = 10
    
    init() {
        hOffset = inset
    }
    
    var body: some View {
            ZStack {
                Rectangle()
                    .fill(.blue)
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: barH)
                RoundedRectangle(cornerSize: CGSize(width: 10, height: 10))
                    .fill(.gray)
                    .frame(width: indicatorW, height: barH/2)
                    .gesture(DragGesture()
                        .onChanged() { value in
                            setHOffset(hOffset + value.translation.width)
                        }
                    )
                    .position(x: indicatorW/2, y: barH/2)
                    .offset(x: hOffset)
                    .preference(key:HProgressKey.self, value: progress())
                    .onGeometryChange(for: CGSize.self) { proxy in
                        proxy.size
                    } action: { newSize in
                        let progress = progress()
                        barW = newSize.width
                        setHOffset(progress * (barW-indicatorW-inset-inset))
                    }
        }
    }
    
    func setHOffset(_ value: CGFloat) {
        hOffset = max(inset, value)
        hOffset = min(hOffset, barW-indicatorW-inset)
    }
    
    func progress() -> CGFloat {
        return (hOffset-inset) / (barW-indicatorW-inset-inset)
    }
}

struct HProgressKey: PreferenceKey {
    static var defaultValue: CGFloat { 0 }
    static func reduce(value: inout CGFloat, nextValue: () -> CGFloat) {
        value = nextValue()
    }
}
    
struct VProgressKey: PreferenceKey {
    static var defaultValue: CGFloat { 0 }
    static func reduce(value: inout CGFloat, nextValue: () -> CGFloat) {
        value = nextValue()
    }
}


import SwiftUI

struct DumbedDownRepresentable : NSViewRepresentable {
    typealias NSViewType = NSClipView
    @Binding var hProgress: CGFloat
    @Binding var vProgress: CGFloat
    
    func makeNSView(context: Context) -> NSClipView {
        let clipView = NSClipView()
        let textView = TextView()
        clipView.documentView = textView
        
        for i in 1...50 {
            textView.string += String(repeating: "\(i) ", count: i)
            textView.string += "\n"
        }
        
        textView.textContainer?.widthTracksTextView = false
        textView.textContainer?.containerSize = CGSize(width: CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude, height: CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude)
        textView.isVerticallyResizable = true
        textView.isHorizontallyResizable = true
        textView.maxSize = CGSize(width: CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude, height: CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude)
        return clipView
    }
    
    func updateNSView(_ clipView: NSClipView, context: Context) {
        print(hProgress, ", ", vProgress)
        let maxH = clipView.documentRect.width - clipView.frame.width
        let maxV = clipView.documentRect.height - clipView.frame.height
        clipView.scroll(to: .init(x: hProgress*maxH, y: vProgress*maxV))
    }
    
    func sizeThatFits(_ proposal: ProposedViewSize, nsView: UXCodeTextView, context: Context) -> CGSize? {
        var size = nsView.intrinsicContentSize
        if let proposedWidth = proposal.width {
            size.width = max(proposedWidth, size.width)
        }
        return size
    }
    
    class TextView: NSTextView {
        override var intrinsicContentSize: NSSize {
            if let tc = self.textContainer, let lm = self.layoutManager {
                lm.ensureLayout(for: tc)
                return lm.usedRect(for: tc).size
            }
            return .zero
        }
    }
}

